# What do I need to know to find a good second drive?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata

I am getting a second hard drive for my hp pavilion a1630n. The hard drive that came with it is: 250 GB SATA, 7200 rpm (WD WD Caviar SE, 8mb cache).  What do I need to know to find a good second drive for this notebook? Should I look at RAID? SATA?... I am not sure the difference between the two.

Comment: SuperUser doesn't do shopping recommendations, but I edited your question to cover the general-knowledge portions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Drive should really work for your desktop situation if you are just using it for basic file storage.

I would suggest a Western Digital.  You can get a terabyte HDD for about $100 bucks now

Comment: Is there any worry to put such a large (1TB) hard drive onto an older computer like this? I know it's just storage, but I'm sure it takes more memory and juice to sift through a hard drive that big. Is that right?

Comment: It's not a problem.  A larger drive doesn't take more power or memory.  The power used by a hard drive is not proportional to its capacity.  The storage on drives is getting denser so they are not physically larger/heavier and don't require more power to operate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't buy a RAID hard drive.  You use a SATA, SAS, or SSD hard drive with a RAID controller to create a RAID volume (logical drive).  I didn't find specs right away for your computer, but most off-the-shelf desktop models don't support RAID.  Even if they did, you typically need matched disks to make it work as expected.  As a novice user, I would avoid RAID.

What I would look for (if you can afford it) is a *good* SSD drive or a [Momentus XT (hybrid)](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=momentus+hybrid&safe=active&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=17605902780622875651&ei=iNMLTYPvKdP4nwf9w4G2Dg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCYQ8wIwAA#) if you can't (with an adapter so it will fit in your desktop).  Remember that a bad SSD is much worse than a traditional SATA drive, so don't be fooled by the cheapies out there as you're looking.  The hybrid option gives near-SSD performance with traditional drive capacities and pricing.

Comment: Here are the specs from hp.com, http://ow.ly/3r4Tv except that I have a Nvidia Geforce 8800 GTS video card, and 4gb of ram.  I don't need anything fancy, just a good solid hard drive. Is that Momentus XT a good fit?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also, It's not a notebook.  It's a desktop.